# Hstore as argument type in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hstore

Is it possible to declare hstore as an argument type while creating a function in postgresql?

```
CREATE FUNCTION samplehstore(uname hstore)
RETURNS SETOF void AS 
DECLARE 
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'uname : %', uname ;        
END;
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just tested:

```
create or replace function samplehstore(_h hstore)
returns text as
$$
begin
    return _h->'a';
end
$$
language plpgsql;

select samplehstore('a=>1'::hstore)
>>> 1
```

Comment: @user2664380 yes you can use hstore type as input parameter of function, my example clearly shows that.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is ideally right, but you just forgot to surround the function body inside a string (the `hstore` part is ok). I recommend doing that this way (see `$$` added):

```
CREATE FUNCTION samplehstore(uname hstore)
RETURNS SETOF void AS $$
DECLARE 
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'uname : %', uname ;        
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The PostgreSQL's functions are basically an string, and dollar-quoting is an syntax similar to single quotes, try this:

```
SELECT $$my string$$, $id$my string$id$, 'my string';
```

The three are equivalents. See the [docs for more information](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING).